# Angular: retreive variables from childcontroller populated select inputs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I got this issue. So I have 3 controllers:

Parent Controllers:  DocumentController
Child Controller1:   XdataController
Child Controller2:   CompanyController

I use the child controllers to retreive data to populate 3 Selector inputs in my front-end form.

How do I access the values of these select boxes that are populated by the controller?

At the moment I am console logging the results and it prints all the variables from the form except the dropdown selectors that are populated by the child controllers.

Here is my code:

**Document Controller:**

```
           app.controller('DocumentController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$timeout', '$parent', function($scope, $http, $state, $timeout, $parent) {

          $http.get($scope.app.u.api+'secure/doc/all', {headers:{'x-access-token':$scope.app.settings.user.token}})
            .then(function(response) {
              $scope.documents = response.data;
              $http.get($scope.app.u.api+'secure/company/all', {headers:{'x-access-token':$scope.app.settings.user.token}})
                .then(function(response) {
                  $scope.companies = response.data; 
                })//then
            })//then

       //add new Document
       $scope.addDocument = function(regData){
        console.log(regData);
        var setter = {
          token: $scope.app.settings.user.token,

          lender_id: $scope.$parent.regData.lender_id,             //ID of one of the subsidiaries in the DB
          lender_country: $scope.$parent.regData.lender_country,   //Name of one of the 44 countries as a String
          borrower_id: $scope.$parent.regData.borrower_id,       //ID of one of the subsidiaries in the DB

          contract_start: regData.contract_start,
          loan_amount: regData.loan_amount,
          loan_start: regData.loan_start,
          loan_term: regData.loan_term,

          interest_rate: regData.interest_rate,
        }

        /*
        $http.post($scope.app.u.api+'secure/doc/new', setter)
        .then(function(response){
          if(!response.data.success){
            $scope.authError = 'Could not access the database';
          }else{
            $timeout(function(){
              $state.reload(); 
            }, 2000);

          }
        });
        */

       };
}]);//controller
```

**Company controller**

```
    app.controller('CompanyController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$timeout', function($scope, $http, $state, $timeout) {


        $http.get($scope.app.u.api+'secure/company/all', {headers:{'x-access-token':$scope.app.settings.user.token}})
        .then(function(response) {
          $scope.companies = response.data;
        })//then
  }]);//controller
```

**Xdata controller**

```
app.controller('XdataController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$timeout', function($scope, $http, $state, $timeout) {

    $http.get($scope.app.u.api+'secure/xdata/countries', {headers:{'x-access-token':$scope.app.settings.user.token}})
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      $scope.countries = response.data;
    })//then

}]);
```

**The form**

```
    <div ng-controller="DocumentController" >
  <h1>Hello from the new documents template</h1>

  <h1>Add new document</h1>
  <form name="regForm" ng-submit='addDocument(regData);'>
    <div class="list-group list-group-sm">


      <!-- LENDER DETAILS -->
      <div class="list-group-item form-group" ng-controller="SubsidiaryController">
       <label>Lender:</label>
       <select class="form-control" ng-model="regData.lender_id">
         <option value="" disabled selected>Select a borrower from your subsidiaries...</option> 
         <option ng-repeat="subsidiary in subsidiaries" value="{{subsidiary._id}}">{{subsidiary.legalname}}</option>
       </select>
      </div>

        <div class="list-group-item form-group" ng-controller="XdataController">
          <label>Country:</label>
       <select class="form-control" ng-model="regData.lender_country">
         <option value="" disabled selected>Which country the lender is from?...</option>
         <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{ country }}">{{ country }}</option>
       </select>
      </div>




       <!-- BORROWER DETAILS -->
        <div class="list-group-item form-group" ng-controller="SubsidiaryController">
          <label>Borrower:</label>
       <select class="form-control" ng-model="regData.borrower_id">
         <option value="" disabled selected>Select a borrower from your subsidiaries...</option>
         <option ng-repeat="subsidiary in subsidiaries" value="{{subsidiary._id}}">{{subsidiary.legalname}}</option>
       </select>
      </div>




      <!-- CONTRACT DETAILS -->
      <div class="list-group-item form-group" >
        <label>When does the contract start? </label>       
        <input class="form-control" type="date" name="contract_start" ng-model="regData.contract_start">
      </div>


      <!-- LOAN DETAILS -->
      <div class="list-group-item form-group">
        <label>What is the Loan Amount (in USD)?</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Total amount" name="loan_amount" ng-model="regData.loan_amount">
       </div>

     <div class="list-group-item form-group">
        <label>When does the loan start? </label>       
      <input class="form-control" type="date" name="loan_start" ng-model="regData.loan_start">
     </div>

      <div class="list-group-item form-group">
        <label>What is the term of the loan (in years)?</label>
        <select name="loan_term" ng-model="regData.loan_term" class="form-control">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select your loan term...</option>
          <option value="1">1 year</option>
          <option value="2">2 years</option>
          <option value="3">3 years</option>
          <option value="4">4 years</option>
          <option value="5">5 year</option>
          <option value="6">6 years</option>
          <option value="7">7 years</option>
          <option value="8">8 years</option>
          <option value="9">9 year</option>
          <option value="10">10 years</option>
        </select>       
      </div>



    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark btn-block" ng-disabled='form.$invalid'>Generate Document</button>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emit event from client controller and capture in parent controller.

```
app.controller('XdataController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$timeout', '$rootScope',
    function ($scope, $http, $state, $timeout, $rootScope) {
        $http.get($scope.app.u.api + 'secure/xdata/countries', {
                headers: {
                    'x-access-token': $scope.app.settings.user.token
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $rootScope.$emit('countries', response.data); // Emit event from child controller
            }) //then
    }
]);

// Inside DocumentController

$rootScope.$on('countries', (event, data)=>{
    console.log(data); // Data from child controller
});
```

**Another example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="OuterCtrl">
        <h5>Outer Div</h5>
        <div ng-controller="InnterCtrl">
            <button ng-click="click()">Inner Div</button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('OuterCtrl', function ($rootScope) {
            $rootScope.$on('countries', (event,data) => {
                alert(data); // Data from child controller
            });
        });

        app.controller('InnterCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
            $scope.click = function () {
                $rootScope.$emit('countries', 'Message from inner div');
            };
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could it be that it should be $rootScope.$on('countries', (data)=>{... 

However, even with this fix the document controller is not console logging anything yet. It should console log the countries, right?

Comment: @RutgerBrns that's correct, check now I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rahul! I am gotta take a good look at your answer and dig deeper into $rootScope (emit and broadcasting), so I get an even clearer idea about what's exactly happening here.